# NoClassDefFoundError using jars

Tags: java, jar

I am new to Java and trying around. Now I would like to learn about network - server client communications. Long story short I found jars on github which should make the start easier. So I downloaded the file and added it to my Modulepath. Everything looked OK while writing a simple start to just connect but when I want to run for testing I get the NoClassDefFoundError ...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/blogspot/debukkitsblog/net/Server
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:855)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:753)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:676)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at fst.serverclient.ssc.SSCNetzwerkTester.main(SSCNetzwerkTester.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blogspot.debukkitsblog.net.Server
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 10 more
```

I do not have any idea what am I doing wrong, the jar should work otherwise it should not be there for download I guess. But the error comes from one of the jar classes called Server:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/blogspot/debukkitsblog/net/Server
```

Comment: It means that the jar you downloaded depends on another jar (the one which contains the class com/blogspot/debukkitsblog/net/Server) but this jar is not in your classpath. When that happens, either you build a "fat jar" which includes all the dependencies (but since you download the jar, you really have no choice to build it on your own), or you download as well the missing jar and add it to your classpath (you will probably have to do that for each dependency added to your original jar)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not sure how I can change that, because I downloaded that jar .../net/Server and this jar look like causing the error. So I don't know what jars else should I download than

Comment: I forgot to write a maybe very important point. At first after implementing the jar to my project I got the following error ..
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for D:\Programs\JavaJar\SimpleServerClient_lib_2.4.1.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SimpleServerClient.lib.2.4.1: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
So I thought I just rename and it will work ;) So I deleted the 2.4.1 at the end. So maybe the renaming is the issue but how could I fix the "invalid module name"?